# How to select cells of a specific row using nth-child

Tags: jquery, row, cell, css-selectors

I have a 3x3 table.

I want to select each td within a specific row. (2nd row for example)

```
$('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td').css("background-color","red");
```

Above code sets only 2nd rows 1st column to red.

I expected it to modify each td in 2nd row but seems i'm missing something.

Why does above code doesn't work as expected?

(**EDIT**: I'm using Chrome 13 with jquery 1.7.1)

Comment: Real HTML demo? The selector works as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/kYZWY/

Comment: @RobW: Shouldn't the selector match *all* `td`'s within the 2nd `tr` rather than the 1st?

Comment: The whole row is matched (FF 10). I however, see that only the first cell is highlighted in Chrome 17.

Comment: @RobW i get the same result in http://jsfiddle.net/kYZWY/ too. It only paints first cell of 2nd row. I'm using google chrome.

Comment: @RobW's demo works fine for me in Chrome 18.

Comment: @Matt: Seems more like a bug in `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: ie8 shows it ok btw (native and compatibility mode)

Comment: @amnotiam: ahh, well investigated! (http://jsfiddle.net/kCQrg/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome seems to be [bugged again](http://jsfiddle.net/kYZWY/) <sup>View this demo in Chrome (observed bug in Chromium 17)</sup>.

Instead of `> td`, you can use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), which is equivalent:

```
$('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)').children().css("background-color","red");
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kYZWY/2/

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify this using standard DOM properties that work in every major browser and while you're at it target it to the actual table you're interested in rather than all tables (which is what your current selector does). This will run faster and more reliably than the jQuery equivalent.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N3MAg/

```
var cells = document.getElementById("your_table_id").rows[1].cells;
for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; ++i) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: @amnotiam: People just love strings.

Answer (score 0):

May be you'll set the bg to the whole row [like this](http://jsbin.com/oyezec/edit#javascript,html)

```
$('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)').css("background-color","red");
```

[This](http://jsbin.com/oyezec/2/edit) approach also gives an identical result

```
$('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)').children().css("background-color","red");
```