# Why can I select an nth-child cell, but not an nth-child row in my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this work:

```
var t = j+1;
$("#mapTable tr:first-child td:nth-child(" + t + ")").addClass("target");
```

but in the same code (immediately below), this does not:

```
t= i+1;
$("#mapTable tr:nth-child(" + t + ") td:first-child").addClass("target");
```

In the trivial example I'm testing in, `i == j == 2`, and there are five rows and columns in the table. Basically, I want to highlight the first cell in the same row and column as the one I'm in right now while iterating through the table.

**Note:** I've found a work around, posted below. Still interested in why the selector doesn't behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of combing stack overflow, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331223/1168038) answer,

There's a much easier way to work with tables without jQuery, and the solution to my problem was to use a function like this:

(in the for loop that creates the table)

```
for(var i=0; i < test1; i++)
{
    tr = $("<tr />");
    for(var j=0; j < test2; j++)
    {
        td = $("<td />");
        if(matchConditionIsMet(i,j))
            matchArr = [i,j];
        td.appendTo(tr);
    }
    tr.appendTo("#mapTable");
}
```

(after loop execution)

```
i = matchArr[0];
j = matchArr[1];
var targ = document.getElementById("mapTable").rows[0].cells[j];
$(targ).addClass("target");

targ = document.getElementById("mapTable").rows[i].cells[0];
$(targ).addClass("target");
```

After spending literally minutes of my life trying to reinvent the wheel, I found that the answer exists in the core of Javascript, sans library.

It still doesn't solve the riddle of why `nth-child()` works sometimes and doesn't other times, but more practically speaking it gives me a way to flag the row header and column header for the target cell.

Hope this saves someone some trouble.